# How do I correctly populate a DataGridView with rows from multipile table adapter queries?

Tags: c#, datagridview, tableadapter

I'm doin an ad-hoc query to get a set of ID's, each of which goes to a table adapter's query, populating rows.

However, I can't figure out any other way to clear other than using the ClearBeforeFill property on the table adapter.

All of this amounts to code that works but I feel is kind of a hack.

Does anyone know the right/better way to do this? (note: i'm aware inline SQL isn't ideal)

```
    var db = new Data.PRDataDataContext();
    verifiedLineItemsTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
    bool flag = true;
    foreach (var affid in db.ExecuteQuery<int>(
        @"
        SELECT Item.affid           
        FROM   dbo.Item INNER JOIN
               dbo.Affiliate ON dbo.Item.affid = dbo.Affiliate.affid
        WHERE  Affiliate.name={0}
        UNION
        SELECT affid
        FROM   dbo.Publisher
        WHERE  name={0}"
        , name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got " + affid);
        verifiedLineItemsTableAdapter.FillByAffId(
            publisherReportDataSet1.VerifiedLineItems, affid);
        if (flag)
        {
            verifiedLineItemsTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = false;
            flag = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would divide it into 2 separate functions and join the up afterward

Similar to this

```
List<int> getItemAffid(string Name) {....//your code here to return a list}

List<int> getPublisherAffid(string Name) {....//your code here to return a list}
```

and then join them up

```
var SearchItemAffid = from a in getItemAffid(<your var>) select a;
var SearchedPublisherAffid = from a in getPublisherAffid(<your var>) select a;

var Combined = SearchedPublisherAffid.Union(SearchItemAffid);
```

**EDIT :** you can then bind it to a grid

```
DataGrid.Datasource = Combined
```